# How do you pass list of values dynamically to where clause in a query in ADF connector?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF so please excuse if this pretty obvious.
I am using Azure ADF to orchestrate data ingestion and using ADF connector to pull data from another cloud.
I have currently hard coded the values in the where clause and looking to manage the list dynamically.
My initial thought was to have the list as a txt/csv file in blob storage and then using lookup activity I can pass the value to the where clause.
The problem is I am getting values as `Prop_0` in an array format and I am not sure how do I pass all the values of the array to the where clause.
I tried `Prop[0]` and it filtered based on the 1st value of the array but I want the query to filter records for all the values from the array.

Is there any way to specify all values of an array with `Prop_0[]`?

```
from view1
where col1 in ('A BC', 'AB C', 'ABC')
```

Output of lookup activity:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "value": [
        {
            "Prop_0": "'A BC'"
        },
        {
            "Prop_0": "'AB C'"
        },
        {
            "Prop_0": "'ABC'"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to use the Append variable activity but did not make much progress either.

Appreciate any help on getting this resolved?

Another alternative I am thinking of is storing the list in Azure SQL table and then using the column heading in a lookup activity.
Is there any other easier/simpler way to handle this?